# Function composition or pipe operator

Tags: clojure

I have two functions:

```
user=> (def tmp (classificator.db/get-questions classificator.db/db))
#'user/tmp
user=> (def result (map classificator.core/transform-data tmp))
#'user/result
```

First function return data which I pass to second function.

I would like to write in one expression without `tmp` variable:

```
user=> (-> (classificator.db/get-questions classificator.db/db) (map classificator.core/transform-data))

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: classificator.core$transform_data  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)
```

Looks like I don't mistake in the `->` macros usage. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread-first macro `->` puts arguments in the first position of the remaining forms, but you want it to go at the end. You can use the thread-last macro `->>` instead:

```
(->> (classificator.db/get-questions classificator.db/db) 
     (map classificator.core/transform-data))
```

or

```
(->> classificator.db/db
     (classificator.db/get-questions)
     (map classificator.core/transform-data)))
```